# Git: prevent committing temporary code

Tags: git

I often forget some temporary code (for debugging or otherwise) in my files and then commit them and push these commits to my remote repository.
This of course can be fixed by reverting the changes, but my commits are becoming cluttered with "forgot to remove xxx"..

I adopted the habit of tagging my temporary code with a "TEMP" comment. But is there a way to customize git so that if it finds this word in a document, a warning (or an error) message is returned?

Thanks

Comment: How about reviewing all of your code changes before you actually commit?

Comment: How about just rebase squashing away your fixups, or amending your commits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a git hook.

In your project directory, is the hidden folder `.git`. Edit the file `.git/hooks` and then create a script like this:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample

Hope that helps

Comment: Why a hook will work and will solve the OP's question, the real truth is that there is no substitute for reviewing one's changes prior to making a commit (i.e. for that time one forgot to use "TEMP" in a comment or another time when that comment *should* be ok to commit).